# listview C# sorting by specific column

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, indexing

How to sort a listview control by a specific column number in WinForms .NET 2.0? e.g. I have a column called "Line Number" whose index is 1, and I want to sort my items in the listview box by that in ascending order.

Comment: See this implementation from Microsoft: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319401

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have used this column sorter in many Winform Projects:

```
private void listView1_ColumnClick(object sender, 
                   System.Windows.Forms.ColumnClickEventArgs e)
{
   ListView myListView = (ListView)sender;

   // Determine if clicked column is already the column that is being sorted.
   if ( e.Column == lvwColumnSorter.SortColumn )
   {
     // Reverse the current sort direction for this column.
     if (lvwColumnSorter.Order == SortOrder.Ascending)
     {
      lvwColumnSorter.Order = SortOrder.Descending;
     }
     else
     {
      lvwColumnSorter.Order = SortOrder.Ascending;
     }
   }
   else
   {
    // Set the column number that is to be sorted; default to ascending.
    lvwColumnSorter.SortColumn = e.Column;
    lvwColumnSorter.Order = SortOrder.Ascending;
   }

   // Perform the sort with these new sort options.
   myListView.Sort();
}
```

**Source**: [Click Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ListViewColumnSorter.aspx)

Answer (score 21):

There is example on MSDN [ListView.ColumnClick article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columnclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): very short and simple. Essentially, you write a `ListViewItemComparer` and use it each time you click a column:

```
 class ListViewItemComparer : IComparer
 {
    private int col = 0;

    public ListViewItemComparer(int column)
    {
        col = column;
    }
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return String.Compare(((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[col].Text, ((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[col].Text);
    }
 }

 class MyForm : Form
 {
    // private System.Windows.Forms.ListView listView1;

    // ColumnClick event handler.
    private void ColumnClick(object o, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
    {
        this.listView1.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer(e.Column);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Dont get why this was down marked. for a quick sorting it works great! Does toggle between asc/desc thats easy enough to do! thanks anyway!

Comment: Just add "using System.Collections;" on your project and this is simple and it works, for a basic ascend sort